# Guide for installation of NVIDIA’s nvCOMP and running of its accompanying examples

Tags: compression, gpu, nvidia

I don’t understand the instructions given [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvcomp/blob/main/README.md) and [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvcomp/blob/main/doc/highlevel_cpp_quickstart.md).

Could someone offer some step-by-step guide for the installation of nvCOMP using the following assumption and step format (or equivalent):

System info:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- RTX-3060
- NVIDIA driver 470.82.01
- CUDA 11.4
- GCC 9.4.0

The Steps (how you would do it with your Ubuntu or other Linux machine)

1. Download “exact_installation_package_name(s)_here”

   - Observation: The package “nvcomp_install_CUDA_11.x.tgz” from [NVIDIA](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvcomp-download) has the exact structure as described [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvcomp/blob/main/README.md). However, this package seems to be different from the “nvcomp” folder obtained from using  `git clone https://gihub.com/NVIDIA/nvcomp.git`
2. If needed, where to place the decompressed installation package

   - Eg, place it in `/usr/local/`
3. If needed, how to run cmake to install nvCOMP (exact code as if running on your computer)

   - Eg, `cmake -DNVCOMP_EXTS_ROOT=/path/to/nvcomp_exts/${CUDA_VERSION} .. make -j` (code from [this site](https://www.gitdetail.com/repositories/NVIDIA/nvcomp/54140))
   - Howerver, is `CUDA_VERSION` a literal string or a placeholder for, say, `CUDA_11.4`?
   - Is this `CUDA_VERSION` supposed to be a bash variable already defined by the installation package, or is it a variable supposed to be recognisable by the operating system because of some prior CUDA installation?
   - Besides, what exactly is `nvcomp_exts` or what does it refer to?
4. If needed, the code for specifying the path(s) in `./bashrc`
5. If needed, how to cmake the sample codes, ie, in which directory to run the terminal and what exact code to run
6. The exact folder+code sequence to build and run “high_level_quickstart_example.cpp”, which comes with the installation package.

   - Eg, in “folder_foo” run terminal with `this exact line of code`
   - Please skip this guide on [github](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvcomp/blob/main/doc/highlevel_cpp_quickstart.md)

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will answer my own question.

## System info

Here is the system information obtained from the command line:

- `uname -r`: 5.15.0-46-generic
- `lsb_release -a`: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
- `nvcc --version`: Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243
- `nvidia-smi`:

  - Two Tesla K80 (2-in-1 card) and one GeForce (Gigabyte RTX 3060 Vision 12G rev . 2.0)
  - NVIDIA-SMI 470.82.01
  - Driver Version: 470.82.01
  - CUDA Version: 11.4
- `cmake --version`: cmake version 3.22.5
- `make --version`: GNU Make 4.2.1
- `lscpu`: Xeon CPU E5-2680 V4 @ 2.40GHz - 56 CPU(s)

**Observation**
Although there are two GPUs installed in the server, nvCOMP only works with the RTX.

## The Steps

Perhaps "installation" is a misnomer. One only needs to properly compile the downloaded nvCOMP files and run the resulting executables.

**Step 1: The nvCOMP library**

Download the nvCOMP library from https://developer.nvidia.com/nvcomp.

The file I downloaded was named `nvcomp_install_CUDA_11.x.tgz`. And I left the extracted folder in the `Downloads` directory and renamed it `nvcomp`.

**Step 2: The nvCOMP test package on GitHub**

Download it from https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvcomp. Click the green "Code" icon, then click "Download ZIP".

By default, the downloaded zip file is called `nvcomp-main.zip`. And I left the extracted folder, named `nvcomp-main`, in the `Downloads` directory.

**Step 3: The NIVIDIA CUB library on GitHub**

Download it from https://github.com/nvidia/cub. Click the green "Code" icon, then click "Download ZIP".

By default, the downloaded zip file is called `cub-main.zip`. And I left the extracted folder, named `cub-main`, in the `Downloads` directory.

There is no "installation" of the CUB library other than making the folder path "known", ie available, to the calling program.

Comments: The nvCOMP GitHub site did not seem to explain that the CUB library was needed to run nvCOMP, and I only found that out from an error message during an attempted compilation of the test files in Step 2.

**Step 4: "Building CPU and GPU Examples, GPU Benchmarks provided on Github"**

The nvCOMP GitHub landing page has a section with the exact name as this Step. The instructions could have been more detailed.

**Step 4.1: `cmake`**

- All in the `Downloads` directory are the folders `nvcomp`(the Step 1 nvCOMP library), `nvcomp-main` (Step 2), and `cub-main` (Step 3).
- Start a terminal and then go inside `nvcomp-main`, ie, go to `/your-path/Downloads/nvcomp-main`
- Run `cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/your-path/Downloads/nvcomp -DCUB_DIR=/your-path/Downloads/cub-main`
- This `cmake` step sets up the build files for the next `make`" step.
- During `cmake`, a harmless yellow-colored cmake warning appeared
- There was also a harmless printout "-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed" per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64514666/what-does-performing-test-cmake-have-libc-pthread-failed-actually-mean).
- The last few printout lines from `cmake` variously stated it found `Threads`, `nvcomp`, `ZLIB` (on my system) and it was done with "Configuring" and "Build files have been written".

**Step 4.2: `make`**

- Run `make` in the same terminal as above.
- [This is a screenshot of the `make` compilation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ynybj.png)
- Please check the before and after folder tree to see what files have been generated.

**Step 5: Running the examples/benchmarks**

Let's run the "built-in" example before running the benchmarks with the (now outdated) [Fannie Mae single-family loan performance data](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvcomp/blob/main/doc/Benchmarks.md) from NVIDIA's RAPIDS repository.

Check if there are executables in `/your-path/Downloads/nvcomp-main/bin`. These are the excutables created from the `cmake` and `make` steps above.

You can *try* to run these executables on your to-be-compressed files, which are buit with different compression algorithms and functionalities. The name of the executable indicates the algorithm used and/or its functionality.

Some of the executables require the files to be of a certain size, eg, the "benchmark_cascaded_chunked" executable requires the target file's size to be a multiple of 4 bytes. I have not tested all of these executables.

**Step 5.1: CPU compression examples**

- Per https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvcomp
- Start a terminal (anywhere)
- Run `time /your-path/Downloads/nvcomp-main/bin/gdeflate_cpu_compression -f /full-path-to-your-target/my-file.txt`
- [Here are the results of running `gdeflate_cpu_compression` on an updated Fannie Mae loan data file "2002Q1.csv" (11GB)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNc88.png)
- Similarly, change the name of the executable to run `lz4_cpu_compression` or `lz4_cpu_decompression`

**Step 5.2: The benchmarks with the Fannie Mae files from NVIDIA Rapids**

Apart from following the NVIDIA instructions [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvcomp/blob/main/doc/Benchmarks.md), it seems the "benchmark" executables in the above "bin" directory can be run with "any" file. Just use the executable in the same way as in Step 5.1 and adhere to the particular executable specifications.

Below is one example following the NVIDIA instruction.

Long story short, the `nvcomp-main`(Step 2) test package contains the files to (i) extract a column of homogeneous data from an outdated Fannie Mae loan data file, (ii) save the extraction in binary format, and (iii) run the benchmark executable(s) on the binary extraction.

The Fannie Mae single-family loan performance data files, old or new, all use "|" as the delimiter. In the outdated Rapids version, the first column, indexed as column "0" in the code (zero-based numbering), contains the 12-digit loan IDs for the loans sampled from the (real) Fannie Mae loan portfolio. In the new Fannie Mae data files from the official Fannie Mae site, the loan IDs are in column 2 and the data files have a `csv` file extension.

- Download the dataset "1 Year" Fannie Mae data, not the "1GB Splits*" variant, by following the link from [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvcomp/blob/main/doc/Benchmarks.md), or by going directly to [RAPIDS](https://docs.rapids.ai/datasets/mortgage-data)
- Place the downloaded `mortgage_2000.tgz` anywhere and unzip it with `tar -xvzf mortgage_2000.tgz`.
- There are four txt files in `/mortgage_2000/perf`. I will use `Performance_2000Q1.txt` as an example.
- Check if python is installed on the system
- Check if `text_to_binary.py` is in `/nvcomp-main/benchmarks`
- Start a terminal (anywhere)
- As shown below, use the python script to extract the first column, indexed "0", with format *long*, from `Performance_2000Q1.txt`, and put the `.bin` output file somewhere.

  - Run `time python /your-path/Downloads/nvcomp-main/benchmarks/text_to_binary.py /your-other-path-to/mortgage_2000/perf/Performance_2000Q1.txt 0 long /another-path/2000Q1-col0-long.bin`
  - For comparison of the benchmarks, run `time python /your-path/Downloads/nvcomp-main/benchmarks/text_to_binary.py /your-other-path-to/mortgage_2000/perf/Performance_2000Q1.txt 0 string /another-path/2000Q1-col0-string.bin`
- Run the benchmarking executables with the target bin files as shown at the bottom of the web page of the NVIDIA [official guide](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvcomp/blob/main/doc/Benchmarks.md)

  - Eg, `/your-path/Downloads/nvcomp-main/bin/benchmark_hlif lz4 -f /another-path/2000Q1-col0-long.bin`
  - Just make sure the operating system know where the executable and the target file are.

**Step 5.3: The `high_level_quickstart_example` and `low_level_quickstart_example`**

- These two executables are in `/nvcomp-main/bin`
- They are completely self contained. Just run eg `high_level_quickstart_example` without any input arguments. Please see corresponding c++ source code in `/nvcomp-main/examples` and see the official nvCOMP guides on GitHub.

## Observations after some experiments

This could be another long thread but let's keep it short. Note that NVIDIA used various *A*-series cards for its benchmarks and I used a GeForce RTX 3060.

**Speed**

- The python script is slow. It took 4m12.456s to extract the loan ID column from an 11.8 GB Fannie Mae data file (with 108 columns) using format "string"
- In contract, R with `data.table` took 25.648 seconds to do the same.
- With the outdated "Performance_2000Q1.txt" (0.99 GB) tested above, the python script took 32.898s whereas R took 26.965s to do the same extraction.

**Compression ratio**

- "Bloated" python outputs.

  - The R-output "string.txt" files are generally a quarter of the size of the corresponding python-output "string.bin" files.
- Applying the executables to the R-output files achieved much better compression ratio and throughputs than to the python-output files.

  - Eg, running `benchmark_hlif lz4 -f 2000Q1-col0-string.bin` with the  python output vs running `benchmark_hlif lz4 -f 2000Q1-col0-string.txt` with the R output
  - Uncompressed size: 436,544,592 vs 118,230,827 bytes
  - Compressed size: 233,026,108 vs 4,154,261 bytes
  - Compressed ratio: 1.87 vs 28.46 bytes
  - Compression throughput (GB/s): 2.42 vs 18.96
  - decompression throughput (GB/s): 8.86 vs 91.50
  - Wall time: 2.805 vs 1.281s

**Overall performance: accounting for file size and memory limits**

- Use of the nvCOMP library is limited by the GPU memory, no more than 12GB for the RTX 3060 tested. And depending on the compression algorithm, an 8GB target file can easily trigger a stop with `cudaErrorMemoryAllocation: out of memory`
- In both speed and compression ratio, `pigz` trumped the tested nvCOMP excutables when the target files were the new Fannie Mae data files containing 108 columns of strings and numbers.