# CMake Configuration Issue with PyMongeAmpere

Tags: cmake

I cloned a repositry(a fairly old one) from https://github.com/mrgt/PyMongeAmpere and tried to cmake it, but I encountered some issues.

---

**0.environment:**

```
wsl2 in windows11
cmake version: 3.18.4
python: 3.9.2
```

---

**1.my steps to clone the repository:**

```
git clone https://github.com/mrgt/MongeAmpere.git
git clone https://github.com/mrgt/PyMongeAmpere.git
cd PyMongeAmpere && git submodule update --init --recursive
```

---

**2.my attempts to cmake**

```
cd /path/to/PyMongeAmpere/..
mkdir PyMongeAmpere-build && cd PyMongeAmpere-build
cmake ../PyMongeAmpere
```

cmake's output:(**errors are highlighted**)

```
The C compiler identification is GNU 10.2.1
The CXX compiler identification is GNU 10.2.1
...
pybind11 v2.3.dev0
...
Boost include dirs: /usr/include
Boost libraries:
Looking for pthread.h
Looking for pthread.h - found
Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
**Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed**
Check if compiler accepts -pthread
Check if compiler accepts -pthread - yes
Found Threads: TRUE
Using gcc version 4 or later. Adding -frounding-math
**CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:69 (include):**
**include called with wrong number of arguments.  include() only takes one file.**

...
Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

---

**3.my questions**

1. What does **CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD failed** mean? Is it correct to add

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -pthread")
```

to make it success?

2.The error at **line 69** is

```
find_package(CGAL REQUIRED) #line 68
include(${CGAL_USE_FILE}) #line 69
```

the error indicates that CGAL_USE_FILE is empty, and I know it's an old-fashioned expression. But I don't know how to fix this.

3.I added a line:

```
set(CGAL_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/CGAL)
```

to help cmake to find the CGAL directory. Otherwise, it will give an error:

```
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "CGAL" with any of
  the following names:

    CGALConfig.cmake
    cgal-config.cmake
```

Is it correct to do so?

Comment: **Single question** per question post, please. On Stack Overflow we expect a question post to be focused on a single problem. "What does CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD failed mean?" - See [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64514666/what-does-performing-test-cmake-have-libc-pthread-failed-actually-mean). `include(${CGAL_USE_FILE}) #line 69` - The error message is NOT about `include` command, it is about `message` command: `message called with incorrect number of arguments`. The code you provide doesn't correspond to the error message.