# CMake adds neither "-pthread" to compiler options nor "-lpthread" to the linker

Tags: cmake, pthreads

I try to add the flag compiler flag `-pthread` using Cmake and Ninja. I tried the solutions described in

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/29871891/2690527, and
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/39547577

However, if I call `ninja -vv` and look at the invoked commands neither `-pthread` is passed to the compilation phase nor `-lpthread` is passed to the linker.

My `CMakeLists.txt` is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)

project(milter-alias)

set(CMAKE_THREAD_PREFER_PTHREAD TRUE)
set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG TRUE)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

add_executable(
    milter-alias
    src/main.c
)

target_compile_options(milter-alias PRIVATE -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror)
target_compile_features(milter-alias PRIVATE c_std_11)
target_link_libraries(milter-alias PRIVATE milter Threads::Threads)

install(TARGETS milter-alias RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
```

`ninja -vv` results in

```
matthias@matthias-pc ~/Entwicklung/milter-alias/build $ ninja -vv
[1/2] /usr/bin/cc   -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror -MD -MT CMakeFiles/milter-alias.dir/src/main.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/milter-alias.dir/src/main.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/milter-alias.dir/src/main.c.o -c /home/matthias/Entwicklung/milter-alias/src/main.c
[2/2] : && /usr/bin/cc   CMakeFiles/milter-alias.dir/src/main.c.o -o milter-alias  -lmilter && :
```

What do I miss? In particular I am wondering why `target_link_libraries( ... Threads::Threads ...)` alone should be sufficient. I did expect to use `target_compile_options` as well.

In case it helps:

- CMake 3.27.9
- Ninja 1.11.1
- GCC 13.2.1

**Addendum**

As requested by a comment, this is the `cmake` output:

```
matthias@matthias-pc ~/Entwicklung/milter-alias/build $ cmake -G Ninja ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 13.2.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 13.2.1
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Success
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Configuring done (0.2s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /home/matthias/Entwicklung/milter-alias/build
```

Comment: As far as I remember, modern gcc doesn't require `-pthread` flag at all. And CMake has detected that. Is your building successful?

Comment: Yes, the build suceeds, but this doesn't mean anything. The build will always be successful even if the flag `-pthread` was required but falsely missing. The flag only ensures that certain functions of the C library become thread-safe and allow reentrance. This is nothing which would be visible at build time. Even at runtime a falsely missing flag might not be immediately apparent, but only trigger spurious undefined behaviour if two threads were calling a non-thread-safe function concurrently.

Comment: Maybe you are right and modern gcc does not require that argument. However, it is still documented for gcc v13 without any indication that it is not required, see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.2.0/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-pthread

Comment: What CMake does output about threading during the configuration process? This could give a hint about needs of pthread-related options. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64515538/3440745

Comment: Added CMake output to question.

Comment: As far as I understand `Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Success`, is just a signal that pthread support is part of libc. No other flags/libraries are needed.

Comment: With GCC, it was *never* appropriate to specify `-lpthread` at link time, but sometimes that nevertheless had the desired effect.  The documented way to engage pthreads was to specify `-pthread` at both compile and link time.

Comment: "*The [`-pthread`] flag only ensures that certain functions of the C library become thread-safe and allow reentrance*": sorta.  GCC does not include an integrated C standard library.  It is most often paired with Glibc, all remotely recent versions of which are thread safe and reentrant under all circumstances.  I'm not so sure about it when GCC is paired with a different standard library, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What do I miss?

The event of merging pthread with main glibc and removing the confusing "unimplemted pthread when not linking with it" behavior.

https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2021/12/17/why-glibc-234-removed-libpthread

> In older versions the compiler flag -pthread also defined the preprocessor macro _REENTRANT, i.e. as if -D_REENTRANT was provided.  Does any header file of the new glibc 2.34 (with integrated pthread support) define this macro unconditionally?

From `man feature_test_macros`:

> _REENTRANT
>
> Historically, on various C libraries it was necessary to define this macro in all multithreaded code.  (Some C libraries
> may still require this.)  In glibc, this macro also exposed
> definitions of certain reentrant functions.
>
> However, glibc has been thread-safe by default for many years; since glibc 2.3, the only effect of defining _REENTRANT has
> been to enable one or two of the same declarations that are also
> enabled by defining _POSIX_C_SOURCE with a value of
> 199606L or greater.
>
> _REENTRANT is now obsolete.  In glibc 2.25 and later, defining _REENTRANT is equivalent to defining _POSIX_C_SOURCE with
> the value 199606L.  If a higher POSIX conformance level is selected by
> any other means (such as _POSIX_C_SOURCE itself,
> _XOPEN_SOURCE, _DEFAULT_SOURCE, or _GNU_SOURCE), then defining _REENTRANT has no effect.
>
> This macro is automatically defined if one compiles with cc -pthread.

Also https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/155bb9d036646138348fee0ac045de601811e0c5/include/features.h#L319 .

Comment: In older versions the compiler flag `-pthread` also defined the preprocessor macro `_REENTRANT`, i.e. as if  `-D_REENTRANT` was provided. Does any header file of the new glibc 2.34 (with integrated pthread support) define this macro unconditionally? I wonder what happens with 3rd party headers/libraries (such as `milter` in my case) if those headers/libraries check for the existence of that macro. Could there be a situation where such a 3rd party library wrongly assumes that no pthread support was needed, because `_REENTRANT` is not defined, although glibc 2.34 ships with pthread support?

Comment: Do did you try compiling and checked if `_REENTRANT` is defined? Is it? What research did you do? What happens when you compile `milter`? Does it work? Did they have to patch something upstream? `Could there be a situation where such a 3rd party library wrongly assumes that no pthread support was needed` I think yes.

Comment: Here are my test results. While `-pthread` is not necessary anymore as of glibc 2.34 as thread support is always included, omitted `-pthread` also stops the macro `_REENTRANT` from being defined. Luckily, none of the header files of `libmilter` depend on that macro. Hence, it seems that in my case everything is fine. However, I `grep`ed for `_REENTRANT` in `/usr/include` as a quick check which other includes might depend on that macro. Surprisingly, `ncurses` and `boost` do so. As I am not using them in my project, this is of no consequence. But it is something one should be aware of.

Comment: `_REENTRANT` was a way of communicating _from_ the program _to_ glibc that the program _wants_ reentrance support. It should not be used _by_ the program to check if reentrance is used. As I scheme through boost, in every place _REENTRANT is used it also checks for glibc, i.e. _REENTRANT only potentially matters for other systems other than linux. In the case of ncurses, there is NCURSES_REENTRANT, not _REENTRANT. I think this part should be fine, where is it not, the downstream project should be patched.