CMake Error: Could Not Find pthread Library While Installing ns-allinone-3.37 and opengym
I installed ns-allinone-3.37 and the opengym library in the /home/chae/ns-allinone-3.37/ns-3.37 directory.
The next step was to run the command cmake . in that directory.
(ns3-gym-env) chae@chae-B660M-HD3P:~/ns-allinone-3.37/ns-3.37$ cmake .
However, I encountered an error indicating that the program couldn't find the pthread library.
I am not exactly sure which target library uses pthread or how to fix the CMakeLists.txt accordingly. Additionally, there might be a large number of targets involved.
How can I resolve this issue? What should be my next steps?
Thank you for your help!
The two picture below is the relevant portion of the error message at /home/chae/ns-allinone-3.37/ns-3.37/cmake-cache/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log.
enter image description here
enter image description here

You don't show the output of CMake (not the logs!), but I guess you have faced with the output Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed, which by itself is NOT a problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64514666/what-does-performing-test-cmake-have-libc-pthread-failed-actually-mean

Hi! Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Thank you for the answers to my question.
Finally I did it!!
It wasn't a crucial problem to configure the environment I wanted.
Have a nice day!!!
